# Push notification alert opens app when unlocking an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications, push-notification

I have developed the iPad app which uses apple push notification. Push notification delivering works fine in all the scenario except when the iPad device is locked and notification is delivered. In this scenario it behaves weirdly and opens the app when you slide to unlock the device without touching the alert/banner. Its happening in iOS versions 4.3, 5.1 and also in 6.0

In apple document they have mentioned as below:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

```
iOS Note: If the user unlocks the device shortly after a remote-notification alert is displayed, the operating system automatically triggers the action associated with the alert. (This behavior is consistent with SMS and calendar alerts.) This makes it even more important that actions related to remote notifications do not have destructive consequences. A user should always make decisions that result in the destruction of data in the context of the application that stores the data.
```

what is the action associated with alert? 
***the operating system automatically triggers the action associated with the alert***

And also I wanted understand what is the default behavior in this scenario?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is not behaving weirdly, as that is the default behaviour. When your notification lights up the screen, the 'slide to unlock' changes into 'slide to view', which will open your app and execute the action related to your notification.

The default action is that nothing happens if you do not specify anything to happen.

For handling a notification (which is the action associated with the alert) please refer to the documentation: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4), section Handling Local and Remote Notifications